# Evaluate $1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

In some problem, I have to use the expression
$$\sum^\infty_{k=0}(-1)^kx^k=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$$
I know about Taylor series, but I'm not sure how to find the equivalent to this. It's similar to the $log(1+x)$ series. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $|y| < 1$,
$$
1 + y + y^2 + \dots + y^n = \frac{1-y^{n+1}}{1-y}
$$

so taking the limit $ n \to \infty$ we get

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty y^k = \frac{1}{1-y}.
$$

Now take $y = -x$ and you get what you want.

Have I answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

Since $(-1)^kx^k=(-x)^k$, you have a geometric series, whose sum is $\dfrac1{1+x}$, when $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

You’re exactly right.

The Taylor series for $\log(1+x)$ is
$$\log(1+x) =x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots$$ so, differentiating both sides, you get
$$\frac{1}{1+x} = 1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$$